# How to Vlookup where column has value, not blank cells?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to lookup an ID from column I, in column A.

```
Dim x As Long

lr = Worksheets("Risk Explorer greeks").Cells(Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row

Range("J2:J2" & lr).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-1], R1C1:R50000C1, 1, False)"
```

I have ~40,000 values in column J, however when I run this code it populates down to cell 237,000.

How can I look up column J where it has a value, and not lookup loads of blank cells?

Alternatively is there a faster way to do this lookup rather than the above formula?

Comment: I suggest you avoid using VLOOKUP by using an INDEX/MATCH instead. INDEX/MATCH much faster than VLOOKUP when dealing with a large number of cells. So, change `"=VLOOKUP(RC[-1], R1C1:R50000C1, 1, False)"` for `"=INDEX( R1C1:R50000C1,MATCH(RC[-1], R1C1:R50000C1,0))"`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're appending the number 37000 to the string "J2:J2", which gives you "J2:J237000".

Replace `Range("J2:J2" & lr)` with `Range("J2:J" & lr)`. You should be good to go.